# Duplicate rows using left join at Sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js

i use LEFT JOIN at Sequelize postgress by limit and offset.
  when i change limit and offset for next page, the end row of last page repeat
 in first row of next page.

Relations:

```
 service.hasMany(servicePicture, { foreignKey: 'ServiceID', targetKey: 'ServiceID' });
 servicePicture.belongsTo(service, { foreignKey: 'ServiceID', targetKey: 'ServiceID' });
```

I using :

```
models.Service.findAll({
attributes: attributes,
where: whereClause,

include:     {

    model: models.ServicePicture ,
    attributes:[
        'ServicePictureID',
        'ServicePicturePath'  
    ],
    where: {IsDeleted : false},
    required:false,

   } ,

subQuery:false,
offset: startRowIndex, 
limit: recordCount,

 })
 .then(serviceModels =>{
resolve(serviceModels);})
```

Comment: How are you setting startRowIndex?  Also, when you use `limit`/`offset`, you should use `order` to enforce the correct pagination.

Answer (score 1):

Use `distinct:true` in your query

```
models.Service.findAll({
attributes: attributes,
where: whereClause,

include:     {

    model: models.ServicePicture ,
    attributes:[
        'ServicePictureID',
        'ServicePicturePath'  
    ],
    where: {IsDeleted : false},
    required:false,

   } ,

subQuery:false,
offset: startRowIndex, 
limit: recordCount,
distinct:true // add this distinct here

 })
 .then(serviceModels =>{
resolve(serviceModels);})
```